# Random Walk probability of M(n)=k

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let X$_i$ be a random variable defined as X$_i$ = 1 if w$_i$ = Head and; X$_i$ = $-$1 if w$_i$ = Tail; P(T)=P(H)=0.5

Define discrete-time stochastic process M(n) as M(0)=0, M(n) = $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ X$_i$

Fix positive integers k and n, what is  P(M(n)=k) ?

Should it be (0.5)$^k$$\times$$\frac{(n-k)!}{(\frac{n-k}{2})!(\frac{n-k}{2})!}$(0.5)$^{\frac{n-k}{2}}$(0.5)$^{\frac{n-k}{2}}$? My idea is like there must exist k steps to move forward to arrive at k. Afterwards, there should be equally steps move back or forward. Is it right? But what if n-k is not even?  Any idea to solve this problem? Is there any formula to solve this type of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *almost* right! Basically, all you've done wrong is that you have implicitly said the first $k$ (or, a particular choice of $k$) steps must be 'forward'.

In order to get $M(n) = k$, you need to have $k$ more $+1$s than $-1$s.
(Let's assume that $k \ge 0$ for the moment; $k \le 0$ is similar.)
This means we need $(n-k)/2$ down ($-1$) and $(n+k)/2$ up ($+1$).
Each trajectory has the same probability, since $P(up) = \tfrac12 = P(down)$, and the probability is $2^{-n}$.
Now, how many such trajectories are there? We simply need to choose $(n-k)/2$ of the $n$ to be down, and the remaining $(n+k)/2$ are then up: this is, by definition, $\binom{n}{(n-k)/2}$.
$$ P(M(n) = k) = \binom{n}{(n-k)/2} 2^{-n}. $$

As you point out, there is an issue if $n-k$ is not even. Note that $M(n)$ has the same parity (ie even/odd) as $n$: $n$ is odd if and only if $M(n)$ is odd. Hence $P(M(n) = k) = 0$ when $n - k$ is odd.